# Quarkus Hibernate Reactive - Transaction not executed (subscribed to) inside an event handler

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache, hibernate-reactive, quarkus-hibernate-reactive

I am using Hibernate Reactive with Panache.
I have the following event handler:

```
  @ConsumeEvent(value = "save-result")
  @ReactiveTransactional
  public Uni<ResultEntity> saveResult(ResultMessage msg) {
    ResultEntity result= msg.getResultEntity();
    result.setComplete(true);
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "======> About to save Result: {0}", result);

    return resultRepository.persistAndFlush(result)
        .onItem().invoke(() -> LOGGER.log(Level.INFO,
            "Result has been saved");
  }
```

The event is being consumed (the log "About to save..." is printed), but **the entity is not being saved**. It is as if the transaction is not being subscribed to. (the log message "Result has been saved" is not being printed either)

I'm running on Quarkus 2.16.7 (prior to that, I tried with 2.12.x with no luck).

Note that I have another ApplicationScoped bean where a similar operation (though more complex) works just fine.

I'm not new to Quarkus (I've been working with it for a couple of months), but I'm not an expert either, and yet I am dumbfounded that this does not work.

Why is the transaction not being executed? Am I missing something?

---

UPDATE:
For testing purposes, I have changed the code a bit, by adding another log line as seen below, to check whether the Uni is being subscribed and apparently it is (since "----> in flow" is being outputted), yet the entity is not persisted and "Result has been saved" is never printed either.

```
@ConsumeEvent(value = "save-result")
  @ReactiveTransactional
  public Uni<ResultEntity> saveResult(ResultMessage msg) {
    ResultEntity result= msg.getResultEntity();
    result.setComplete(true);
    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "======> About to save Result: {0}", result);

    return Uni.createFrom().voidItem().onItem()
        .invoke(() -> LOGGER.log(Level.INFO,"----> in flow"))
        .onItem().transformToUni(unused -> resultRepository.persistAndFlush(result)
        .onItem().invoke(() -> LOGGER.log(Level.INFO,
            "Result has been saved")));
  }
```

I suspect that it might be an issue similar to https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/12925 or to https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/14591 but I cannot confirm that.

Comment: Can you provide a test case? At first glance, nothing seems wrong in your snippet

Comment: Thanks @DavideD'Alto . See my answer for this issue. I'll try to setup a reproducing test case and open an issue when I'll have the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I added `.onFailure().invoke(Throwable::printStackTrace)` right after `persistAndFlush` and saw that the operation threw a HibernateException.

This means that the exceptions are silently captured and ignored when executed within a `@ConsumeEvent` method, and therefore the transaction never completes. (similar to the closed issues described [here](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/12925) and [here](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/14591)).

Seems like another issue needs to be opened for this.